# Rails session variable (shopping cart)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, session-variables, cart

I'm trying to save the items the customer can add to my shopping cart in a session variable.
Below is my index method in the cart controller. The ID of the item is saved in @idtemp. Next I create a new array session[:content]. Then I find the item with the ID saved in @idtemp and return it as an array, which is used in the view to display the table. The problem is, everytime an item is added and the index function is called, session[:contenc] is set to [], deleting the cart, which means that a newly added item overwrites the last one.
Now I want this fixed so that a newly added item is added to the array without overwriting the last one,  but I dont know how. I tried to initialize the session variable outside of index but that didnt work somehow. I know this is piss easy but I am pretty exhausted and cant figure it out.

def index

```
  @idtemp = session[:cart]

  session[:content] = []
  session[:content] = session[:content] << (Artikel.find([@idtemp]))

  @cart = session[:content]
```

end

-----view:

<% @cart.each do |id,quantity| %>
      ...
      ...

Comment: I've done a long answer below, but a short answer to just fix your current setup is to change `session[:content] = []` to `session[:content] ||= []` so it will keep it if it already has it, and use an empty array if not.  I don't know what the next line is supposed to be doing so can't advise on that.  I think that you can remove `= session[:content]` from the middle though.  It's really confusing to try to work out what you're trying to do, which is where my "start from scratch" answer comes in.

Comment: Also i'd advise against storing model instances in the session, as you are doing here.  Store ids instead.

Answer (score 1):

If i was you i would store the cart and its contents in the database.  Then all the session has to do is to remember either the cart id, or the id of the user, if they're logged in (once you've got the user you can get the cart).  I'd set it up something like this (which you can adjust for your own schema - Artikle or whatever instead of Product)

```
class Cart
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :cart_products

class CartProduct
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
  #extra field - quantity
```

When the page loads, look to see if you have session[:cart_id].  if you do, you can load the cart, and its associated products if need be.  If not, then create a cart object and set session[:cart_id] to that.

If you have a logged in user (ie session[:user_id] or somesuch) then you can set `current_user` to that user, and set their cart.

I would manage this via some protected methods in ApplicationHelper

```
#in application.rb
def current_user
  if @current_user
    return @current_user
  elsif session[:user_id] && user = User.where(:id => session[:user_id]).first
    @current_user = user
    return @current_user
  end
end

#there's a bit of repetition in here but it should give you the idea
def current_cart
  unless @current_cart
    if current_user
      cart = current_user.cart || Cart.create(:user => current_user)
      @current_cart = cart
    elsif session[:cart_id]
      @current_cart = Cart.where(:id => session[:cart_id]).first || Cart.create
    else
      @current_cart = Cart.create
    end
  end
  return @current_cart
end
```

Now, whenever you want to refer to the current user, or the current cart, in your controller and view code, just say `current_user` or `current_cart`.  The instance variables inside each method mean that if it's been set once in this request then it won't use the logic again - it will just use the one it already saved in the instance variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I feel like there has to be an easier way. This is just a task I have to do and a very  simple and basic webshop too. There has to be a way to store the Articles outside of the index method, so they dont get overwritten everytime it is called.

Comment: Can you expain what session[:cart] and session[:content] are **supposed** to hold?  Like when you say "the id of the item", what are you referring to?  Did the user just select this?  How did they do that?  How is that communicated back to the server?

Comment: The items are added via pressing the add to cart button on the main page: <%= button_to 'Add to Cart', :controller => :cart, :action => :add , :id => uebersicht%>. The :id then is stored in @idtemp. Then I am using Artikel.find to find the article with the matching ID and then store it in session[:cart]. This variable session[:cart] is supposed to store the items in the cart, but currently I am overwriting them. I am sorry, I am a beginner, I know this is probably a horrible way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, adapting your existing system, i would do it like this.  We'll have one session variable, which is a hash storing the ids of Artikels and the quantity of each, with this structure:  `session[:cart] = {123 => 1, 456 => 2}` where 123 and 456 are Artikel ids.

```
def add
  session[:cart] ||= {}
  session[:cart][params[:id]] ||= 0
  session[:cart][params[:id]] += 1
end

def index 
  session[:cart] ||= {}
end
```

now in your view you can say

```
<% session[:cart].each do |artikel_id, quantity| %>
  <% artikel = Artikel.where(:id => artikel_id).first %>
  ...
```

Comment: thanks, I will try that! But just for understanding, why exactly doesn't this work (writing it in another answer below):

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i dont understand:

```
def index
@idtemp = session[:cart]               # @idtemp is now an ID e.g. '1'
session[:inhalt] = []                  # session[:inhalt] is now an empty array []
addedarticle = Artikel.find(@idtemp)   # addedarticle is an article e.g.:{ID=>'1',title=>'Mouse'}
session[:inhalt].concat([addedarticle]) # session[:inhalt]  is now  [{...}] where {...} = article
@cart = session[:inhalt]                # @cart = [{...}]
end
```

This works. An item is added to the cart and @cart is an array containing this item, it can now be used in the view. The only thing that has to be done now is to make sure that the next added item wont override the old ond. You said i can simply replace session[:inhalt] = []  with session[:inhalt] ||= [],
however, doing this leads to an error:

NoMethodError in Cart#index

undefined method `title' for "#":String

```
<% @cart.each do |id| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= image_tag id.Image_URL %></td>
          <td>
            <div class="title"><%=  id.title %></div>
            <br>
```

It seems to me that @cart is not properly "filled". Its supposed to be an array of articles (=hashes) e.g. [{id => 1, title ='mouse'}, {id => 2, title = 'whatever'}], so i can iterate over it with the each do method and display them. But according to the error it is trying to extract the title from a string. What could be the cause of that?
If I can fix this, I am done with the task. Btw, thanks for helping me out so far :)

Comment: replace "undefined method `title' for "#":String" with "undefined method `Image_URL' for "#":String"